# Cannot connect to remote SQL Server over VPN, yet I can ping?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vpn, juniper-network-connect

My VPN appears to be working, since without it I cannot ping the server. When I establish VPN connection I am able to both ping and Remote into the virtual server but cannot connect, getting this message:

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=18193; handshake=14371;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

The curious thing about this is I am able to connect on my old machine using the same VPN software, on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Are TCP/IP connections enabled for SQL Server. Make sure these are enabled.

- Start SQL Server Configuration Manager. Click Start, point to All Programs, and click Microsoft SQL Server. Click Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the console pane, expand SQL Server Network Configuration.
- In the console pane, click Protocols for .
- In the details pane, right-click TCP/IP, and then click Enable.
- In the console pane, click SQL Server Services.
- In the details pane, right-click SQL Server (), and then click Restart, to stop and restart the SQL Server service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. TCP/IP is already enabled. As I said, I am able to connect on my old machine but not my new one.